# display selected file after view reload in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a project in ASP.NET MVC 5, there is a requirement to upload image file, I can upload the image to the server, what I am facing is when there is an error in the view submitted I return the view model with some error message to be displayed on the view so that the user is not requested to select the image again, all the form fields data in the view are getting populated except the file which previously selected is not. Please help me the way to achieve this.

Here is the code I have to select the image

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Logo, null, new { type = "file"})
```

here is the model field

```
   [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Logo
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, you cannot set the value of a file input in the controller, so if you want to avoid having the user select the file again if you return the view, you must first save the file (it could be to a temporary location) and display an indicator to the user that the file has been uploaded. For example, your model might contain the following properties

```
public HttpPostedFileBase Logo { get; set; }
public string LogoFileName { get; set; }
public string LogoPath { get; set; }
```

and in the controller method, save the file and set the `FileName` (i.e. `model.LogoFileName = Logo.FileName;`) and `Path` properties. Then in the view, add a conditional statement to render the `FileName` if it exists, or display the file input if it does not, for example

```
if(Model.LogoFileName == null)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Logo, new { type = "file" })
}
else
{
    @DisplayFor(m => m.LogoFileName)
}
```